# Why do I keep getting name errors? Euler 2 Python

Tags: python, variables

Whenever I define each of the variables in the function I get a error such as "NameError: name 'Tempsum' is not defined." When I make them global variables, I get an error such as "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Tempsum' referenced before assignment"

```
Tempsum=0
FirstNum = 1
SecondNum = 2
SumofFibinaci= 0 
def Fibinaci_calculator():
    while Tempsum <= 4000000:
        Tempsum= SecondNum 
        m= 2
        if Tempsum % m == 0: 
            SumofFibinaci += Tempsum 
        Tempsum = SecondNum+ FirstNum
        FirstNum= SecondNum 
        SecondNum= Tempsum
print SumofFibinaci
pass
print Fibinaci_calculator
```

Comment: please post the **full text** of the error you are getting with this code.

Comment: Also, why would you make temporary state variables for a method global? That's just a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the `UnboundLocal` error `Tempsum` is not a global in the function scope. You assign to it, so it is a local unless explicitly stated otherwise.

You don't *need* `Tempsum` to be a global here. Move the `Tempsum = 0` line into the function. This applies to all your variables:

```
def Fibinaci_calculator():
    Tempsum = 0
    FirstNum = 1
    SecondNum = 2
    SumofFibinaci = 0 

    while Tempsum <= 4000000:
        Tempsum = SecondNum 
        m = 2
        if Tempsum % m == 0: 
            SumofFibinaci += Tempsum 
        Tempsum = SecondNum + FirstNum
        FirstNum = SecondNum 
        SecondNum = Tempsum

    return SumofFibinaci
```

I presume you want `SumofFibinaci` returned.

Don't forget to *call* your function:

```
print Fibinaci_calculator()
```

Comment: Might also want to address the `print Fibinaci_calculator` which almost certainly isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help that fixed the function! (I am still pretty new to python)